# Filebeat multiline pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCKpI.png)

In the picture stacktrace of log message taking the new log line
I want them in one log.
How to do that ?
Here is my pattern

```
  multiline.pattern: '^[[:space:]]'
  multiline.negate: false
  multiline.match: after
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the log sample provided in the screenshot, seems like each new event is starting with date so a multiline pattern like below should work.

```
multiline.type: pattern
multiline.pattern: '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
multiline.negate: true
multiline.match: after
```

I have previously done a similar thing for ingesting IBM BPM System logs and had to increase `multiline.max_lines` to `1000` as the default 500 was not sufficient for getting the entire stack trace ingested.